# Work is blocking an SSH connection, what is the easiest workaround?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, sftp, ssh-tunnel

My work laptop/network is blocking an SSH connection (that I can make with my cellphone so I know it's valid)? What is the easiest away around it?

I'm fine with a small fee to reroute or whatever. (It's probably doesn't matter, but it's corn.stanford.edu that I'm trying to access from work).

Comment: Be warned: for going around blocks that companies put in place, you'll risk losing your job

Comment: Why are you trying to circumvent your company's IT controls/policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often port 443 is not blocked (because of the difficulties in proxying SSL traffic). They might do packet inspection to see if the traffic is 'sane' HTTPS, but I've seen many corporate networks where 443 was unfiltered.

You can try to reconfigure your SSH daemon to listen on port 443 (OpenSSH `Listen` directive) and specify the port in your SSH client.

Comment: I'm going to read more on how SSH works and then try this, thank you!

Comment: @sighmer Here's an example [`sshd_config`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/BSD-Linux/sshd_config) with the listen port and address specified

Answer (score 0):

Does your "work network" configuration allow Telnet or Remote Desktop connections? If yes, you can connect to another device (for example use Remote Desktop to connect to another PC at home) and then use that device to make the required SSH connection.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this right now-- I found our internal build server allows outside SSH.  So first I connect to the build server, then to outside from there.  The lag is still decently low.